# (Javascript Issue) getElementById can't get element even though I can see it in Chrome inspector

Tags: javascript, django-templates, getelementbyid

everyone,

I'm writing a Web Application with Django.
My problem is actually with one of the templates where I created a javascript function to copy information from one form to another.

I'm trying to copy two values from P tags, one of them is working and the other one is not.

So, here's what I have.
This is my first form in which I'm loading a table with contact names and document ids.
Also in this table the first column for each register is a radio button where I'm setting the onchange event to my javascript function 'copyContact()'.

The table is created dynamically for each contact found in DB, and to proper copy the values for the selected radio, I'm also giving an id for each cell dynamically with the contact_id info that I have.

So basically the First Name info of the contact id 15 will have `id="first_name_15"` and so on.

```
                        <div class="row flex-nowrap border-bottom mx-1">
                            <div class="col-1">
                                <p class=" my-2"><input class="form-check-input shadow-sm contactRadio" type="radio" name="contactRadio" id="contact{{ contact_contact_id }}" onchange="copyContact(this)" value="{{ contact.contact_id }}"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <p class="text-wrap my-2" id="first_name_{{ contact.contact_id }}">{{ contact.contact_first_name }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <p class="text-wrap my-2" id="last_name_{{ contact.contact_id }}">{{ contact.contact_last_name }}</a></p>
                            </div>
                            <!-- div class="col-2">
                                <p class="text-wrap my-2">{{ contact.get_document_type_display }}</p>
                            </div-->
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <p class="text-wrap my-2" id="doc_no_{{ contact.contact_id }}">{{ contact.document_no }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Then in my second form is where user should type the Customer information that is being created and the contact selected in first form will be associated with created customer. In order to make user's life easier I want to copy contact info from contact to customer by default after radio selection, then user might change it if necessary.

Here's the second form which is based on Django's Form model.

```
<!-- CUSTOMER FORM -->
                <h4>Informações do Cliente:</h4>
                <input type="text" hidden="true" name="selected_contact" id="selected_contact">
                <div class="row mb-1">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Cliente:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        {{ customer_form.customer_name }}
                        <!-- input class="form-control form-control-sm shadow-sm" type="text" value="{{ customer.customer_name }}" -->
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row mb-1">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Tipo:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        {{ customer_form.customer_type }}
                        <!-- input class="form-control form-control-sm shadow-sm" type="text" required value="{{ customer.get_customer_type_display }}" -->
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row mb-1">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Documento:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        {{ customer_form.document_type }}
                        <!-- input class="form-control form-control-sm shadow-sm" type="text" value="{{ customer.get_document_type_display }}" -->
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row mb-1">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Número Doc:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        {{ customer_form.document_no }}
                        <!-- input class="form-control form-control-sm shadow-sm" type="text" value="{{ customer.document_no }}" -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /CUSTOMER FORM -->
                {% if customer_form.errors %}

                    {% for field in customer_form %}
                        {% for error in field.errors %}
                            <div class="alert alert-danger p-1">
                                {{ field|add:': -'|add:error|escape }}
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}

                    {% for error in customer_form.non_field_errors %}
                        <div class="alert alert-danger p-1">
                            {{ error|escape }}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}

                {% endif %}
                <!-- /CUSTOMER FORM -->
```

By using the inspector in chrome I could check that the inputs created by Django Framework have ids.
So the two fields that would receive the values from contact have the following ids:
`id_customer_name`
and
`id_document_no`
[Image with input IDs in chrome Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAGRK.png)

Then I created the javascript function to copy from first contact form to second customer form.
Here's what I wrote:

```
<script>
    function copyContact(radioItem) {
        var fname = document.getElementById("first_name_" + radioItem.value);
        var lname = document.getElementById("last_name_" + radioItem.value);
        var cname = fname.innerHTML + " " + lname.innerHTML;
        var doc = document.getElementById("doc_no_" + radioItem.value);

        var cust_name = document.getElementById("id_customer_name");
        var cust_doc = document.getElementById("id_document_no");

        cust_name.value = cname;
        cust_doc.value = doc.innerHTML;

        var contact = document.getElementById("selected_contact");
        contact.value = radioItem.value;
    }
</script>
```

My function is being called everytime the user selects a new radio button in contact's form.
The problem that I have is that `getElementById` does not seem to be working for element `id_document_no`.

When I select the radio, first_name and last_name of the contact selected is concatenated and sent to `id_customer_name` input correctly, but this is not happening for `id_document_no` element for some reason that I don't know.
In this line of the function:
`var cust_doc = document.getElementById("id_document_no");`
[Image of both forms executing the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkrED.png)

By changing the function and sending contact's document info to id_customer_name (for debugging purposes only) `var cust_doc = document.getElementById("id_customer_name");`, I could see that my function is working at least to get document value.
[Image of form working with document value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9x5Q.png)

Then I assume the problem is with `getElementById`, but I'm not sure.

So does anyone know what might be happening here? Which id did I mispelled?
Cause I'm pretty sure is a dumb mistake.

Sorry for the long post.

Comment: Most time ife seen this error is wrong scoping. Using `var` instead of `const`or `let`can cause that.
I would suggest not using html-id based values (or store these values in a static or global object). Use the html custom data tag (thats what it's for: custom data). I would install listeners on build time of the elements for copying and that stuff. With that you can be sure that every item has it's listeners.

Comment: I'm actually new to HTML and any thing related to it. I was not aware of variables scopes or even custom data attributes.
After a quick search I discovered that the scope should not matter for this issue. Anyway I did execute some test with all of these types of variables with no success.
As for the custom data attributes, it is a cool concept, however it does not address my issue, since this would help me to store the data and not to copy it to other elements. Also I'm not sure how custom data would work with Django framework since inputs are created automatically. I'll try to look that up.

Answer (score 0):

I still didn't found the issue with my code and why is not working properly.
Anyway, I found a work around for it, which was to refactor the name of the field from 'document_no' to 'document_number'. This includes template, django form and model, which implies also changing the column name in database.

I guess I'll never know the real issue. ¯_(ツ)_/¯